# How to load (and update) an image whose URL is the sum of two forms

Tags: angularjs, forms, binding

I'm trying to get a page where you get an image based on two forms: when you enter the page, the URL is the sum of the two first entries of the forms, but when you change them, the image updates.

This code outputs "undefinedundefined" in the label of placehold

app.js

```
app.controller('dtbCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.selected1 = '1';
  $scope.selected2 = '2';
  $scope.one = [
    {value: '1', label: '1'},
    {value: '2', label: '2'},
    {value: '3', label: '3'},
    {value: '4', label: '4'}
  ];
  $scope.two = [
    {value: '1', label: '1'},
    {value: '2', label: '2'},
    {value: '3', label: '3'}
  ];
  $scope.pic = 'http://www.placehold.it/1618x1000?text=' + $scope.one.label + $scope.two.value;
});
```

page.jade

```
  .title Title
  .thumbnail
    img.img-responsive(ng-src='{{pic}}')
    .caption
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.text-center
        label Label: 
        button.btn.btn-default.navbar-btn(type='button', ng-model='selectedOne', bs-options='one.value as one.label for pitch in ones', bs-select='')
          | Select 
          span.caret
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.text-center
        label Label: 
        button.btn.btn-default.navbar-btn(type='button', ng-model='selectedTwo', bs-options='two.value as two.label for two in twoes', bs-select='')
          | Select
          span.caret
```

And this outputs nothing

page.jade

```
.content(ng-controller='dtbCtrl')
  .title Title
  .thumbnail
    img.img-responsive(ng-src='{{pic + one.value + two.value}}')
```

app.js

```
$scope.pic = 'http://www.placehold.it/1618x1000?text=';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to use selectedOne and not one?

```
img.img-responsive(ng-src='{{pic + selectedOne.value + selectedTwo.value}}')
```

Comment: Oh lol yeah, it solved it. Thank you dude! Will accepte your answer when the timer expires!